# New washer overflows from the stand pipe

Tags: plumbing, washer

I just got a new washer and it’s overflowing from the stand pipe. My old washer was in the same stop and the standpipe never overflowed. I took a garden hose and put it in the drain and let it run for like 5 minutes and it was draining fine. I’m wondering if the new washer ( Samsung WA45K7600AW) is outputting the water too fast for my drain to handle it. Is that even possible? Just looking at the drain pipes of the old and the new washer, I can see the new one is wider. Please help!

Comment: A larger tube, could result in an increase of volume flowing out, as well as the new washer may have a more powerful pump. As an answer below suggests, try adding a section of pipe to the drain pipe, if possible.

Comment: New washing machines pump out way faster than old ones. A2” line is required to keep up with the gpm

Comment: http://www.fixya.com/support/t114258-water_overflowing_from_drain_pipe.  Here are some solutions that may help

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/147629. This too

Answer (score 1):

This situation indicates that there is a plumbing drain problem. The easiest thing to try is adding some height to the stand pipe with a coupling and a pipe section. 
If you can add some detail and maybe a picture we can advise you further.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Answer Incase someone runs into similar situation. i tried to snake the drain my self but it didn’t go far. I thought I was doing something wrong since the water from the older washer and garden hose was making its way down. Finally got the plumber out and opened up the drywall to the p-trap and cut the pipe open. The pipe was disgustingly clogged. I’m not sure how any of the water was making it’s way down the drain to begin with.