# How can I accommodate newer washing machines with older drains?

Tags: drain, washer, overflow

There is a [similar thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147609/how-can-i-accommodate-high-washing-machine-drain-flow-rates-with-older-plumbing) on this topic.  I've got a new LG WT1101CW top load washer and our drain pipe can't keep up with the flowrate coming from the washer.  It's a great idea to add a larger diameter tube to the drain pipe to allow the excess water time to drain away.

Is there any significance to the second 2" pipe at the outlet side of the trap? Or is this just another drain pipe coming from "upstairs"?

[image: Proposed solution from the other question]

Comment: No photo? 2nd pipe? Connecting to a new washer with old drains what is the problem?

Comment: I can't imagine that your washer is overwhelming a 1-1/2" pipe. Its own drain is probably 3/4" at best. That's less than a quarter the size. What is the actual problem?

Comment: New washers after overwhelm old 1.5 pipes.  The big pipe in your picture serves as a reservoir for the volume of water pumping out.    the smaller pipe is likely an air admittance valve for a less than optimal venting option.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any significance to the second 2" pipe at the outlet side of the trap?

No. The vertical pipe downstream of the trap is either another drain coming in from above or a vent stack. It isn't involved with the capability of the 3" section to provide some surge capacity for the draining washer.

(Well, I suppose it *does* add a little bit of capacity, insofar as water can fill that drain/vent pipe up to the level of the opening at the top of the 3" section. So that's a little bit of surge capacity. But it isn't its primary purpose.)